# a database error :"No value given for one or more required parameters."

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a data grid that I should insert its columns values to an access database but I have problem with `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`

My project is not finished just because of this error. Here is my code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < (dataGridFactorRent.Rows.Count) - 1; i++)
{
    string query =
        @"INSERT INTO tbl_RentFactor([ID],DateNow,customerName, objectName, 
          objectNumber,unitCost,objectCost,paidMoney,restOfMonyy,customerID,DateBack)
          VALUES ("+ID+",'" + lbldate.Text + "','" + cmdCustomName.Text + "'," +
              dataGridFactorRent.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + ",
              " + dataGridFactorRent.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + ",
              " + dataGridFactorRent.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value + ",
              " + dataGridFactorRent.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value + ",
              '" + txtPaid.Text + "','" + lblRemained.Text + "',
              "+customerID+",'"+lbldate.Text+"')";

    con.Open();
    command.CommandText =query;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```

Comment: Debug and set break point before `ExecuteNonQuery` and check the `query`. test it on the database manually. avoid those errors you can use parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in one of the comments above, you should start by changing your code to use a *parameterized query*. That will relieve you of the need to delimit values, and will also make your code safer. In addition, you should take advantage of the `using` statement to let .NET manage resources better.

After making those changes your code would look more like this:

```
string query =
    @"INSERT INTO tbl_RentFactor([ID],DateNow,customerName, objectName, 
      objectNumber,unitCost,objectCost,paidMoney,restOfMonyy,customerID,DateBack)
      VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
con.Open();
for (int i = 0; i < (dataGridFactorRent.Rows.Count) - 1; i++)
{
    using (var command = new OleDbCommand(query, con));
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", ID);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", lbldate.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", cmdCustomName.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dataGridFactorRent.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dataGridFactorRent.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dataGridFactorRent.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dataGridFactorRent.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtPaid.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", lblRemained.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", customerID);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", lbldate.Text);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
con.Close();
```

If you still receive an error after making those revisions then double-check the field names in your INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

It means a column is not found in the table, (so Access thinks it's a parameter). Usually you misspelled something. It seems likely "restOfMonyy" should be "restOfMoney". If not, debug the application and get the exact string built and make a query with it and see what happens.